# Can't assign requested address when trying to connect to socket php

Tags: php

***All this code is run on my local machine***

Hi.

I am trying to learn how to properly use sockets.

I created two scripts, the following:

socket.php :

```
<?php

$address = "10.0.1.13";
$port = 19132;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

if($socket === false){
    console("Failed to create socket.");
    exit(1);
}

if(socket_bind($socket, $address, $port) === false){
    console("CANNOT BIND SOCKET -BYE!");
    exit(1);
}

$stop = false;
$start = microtime(true);

console("Socket started ($address) : $port");

while(!$stop){
}

socket_close($socket);

console("Script stopped.");

function console($message){
    echo $message . "\n";
}

?>
```

reader.php :

```
<?php

$address = "10.0.1.13";
$port = 19132;

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

if (($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if(socket_connect($socket, $address, $portph) === false){
    console("CANNOT CONNECT SOCKET -BYE!");
    exit(1);
}

//socket_set_nonblock($socket);

console("success!");

function console($message){
    echo $message . "\n";
}

?>
```

The goal is too run socket.php, and have reader.php connect to the socket. Though, I am always getting `Can't assign requested address when trying to connect to socket` with reader.php. I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `$portph`? Shouldn't that be `$port`?

Comment: Always enable `error_reporting(E_ALL)` so you see warnings about incorrect variable names.

Comment: @Barmar wow .. $portph was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per PHP.net

```
Note:
This function must be used on the socket before socket_connect().
```

you can refer to  - [http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php][1]